# SQLite gives "duplicate column name" , but there is no duplicate column name

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

It is saying I have duplicate column names but I don't. Take a look at this code

This is my Schema class:

```
public  class CrimeDBSchema {

    public static final class CrimeTable{
        public static final String NAME = "crimes";


        public static final class Cols{

            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            public static final String TITLE = "title";
            public static final String DATE = "date";
            public static final String SOLVED = "solved";

        }

    }
}
```

and this is class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper :

```
public class CrimeBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "crimeBase.db";

    public CrimeBaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table "+ CrimeTable.NAME + "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.TITLE + ", "+
                CrimeTable.Cols.DATE + ", " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.SOLVED + ")");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

and AndroidStudio thinks this is my sql statement :

```
create table crimes(_id integer primary key autoincrement, uuid, uuid, uuid, uuid)
```

when clearly all of four column names are different and are not "uuid". Any ideas?

Comment: BTW why create the DB in your app? You can precreate it and deploy it as Asset with your app. Way easier.

Comment: clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: @juergend Or, you know, https://github.com/requery/requery for example

Comment: yes yes, how a first time sqlite user didnt think to deploy as asset or use some object mapper, how silly of me. anyways, when in doubt, rebuild the project, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You define Primary key as integer datatype but what about others.

```
public static final class Cols{
      public static final String ID = "_id";
      public static final String UUID = "uuid";
      public static final String TITLE = "title";
      public static final String DATE = "date";
      public static final String SOLVED = "solved";
}
```

your db.execSQL should be like that(define the column data type)

```
db.execSQL("create table "+ CrimeTable.NAME + "(" +
                CrimeTable.Cols.ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.UUID + " text, " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.TITLE + " text, "+
                CrimeTable.Cols.DATE + " text, " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.SOLVED + " text)");
```

Comment: there is no need to define types.